# Process YAML File step of the Kubernetes plugin throwing error if the image name has / slash

Tags: plugins, kubernetes, ucd

The image in the deployment yaml is in the below format :

```
'${DockerRegistry}/${orgName}/${projectName}/${ImageName}:${version}'
```

There are 3 forward slashes in the image name after the docker registry name and this is causing an error. I tried with Kubernetes plugin of 16, 17, 18 & 19 and Process Yaml step of Kubernetes is throwing the below error.

```
Loading /opt/ibm-ucd/agent/var/work/lr-central-credit-register/common/openshift/dc.yml The desired versions for existing image components is [:] Creating ibm-ucd-kubernetes.yaml Creating component: cbrpoc-loan-requests-cbrpoc-loan-requests/lr-central-credit-register Caught: java.io.IOException: 400 Error processing command: Name cannot contain the following characters: / \ [ ] % java.io.IOException: 400 Error processing command: Name cannot contain the following characters: / \ [ ] % at com.urbancode.ud.client.UDRestClient.invokeMethod(UDRestClient.java:225) at com.urbancode.ud.client.ComponentClient.createComponent(ComponentClient.java:180) at processyaml.createComponent(processyaml.groovy:481) at processyaml.this$4$createComponent(processyaml.groovy) at processyaml$_run_closure6.doCall(processyaml.groovy:362) at processyaml.run(processyaml.groovy:325)
```

Comment: I only see 2 slashes in your format sample, where is the third one?

Comment: There is a slash name between orgname and project name also       "${DockerRegistry}/${orgName}/${projectName}/${ImageName}:${version"     updated the question

Answer (score 0):

According to the official [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/#overview) of `Docker Registry HTTP API V2`

> A repository name is broken up into path components. A component of a
>   repository name must be at least one lowercase, alpha-numeric
>   characters, optionally separated by periods, dashes or underscores.
>   More strictly, it must match the regular expression
>   [a-z0-9]+(?:[._-][a-z0-9]+)*. If a repository name has two or more
>   path components, they must be separated by a forward slash (“/”). The
>   total length of a repository name, including slashes, must be less
>   than 256 characters.

Please make sure you are using `Docker Registry HTTP API V2` and follow all the above rules.

While the `V1` registry protocol is usable, there are several problems with the architecture that have led to `V2`.

Additionally, you can try to use [Docker Tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description)

> Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE

More info with examples lined above.

Please let me know if that helped.